# How to set retryAssertionTimeout based on environment in Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to set the retryAssertionTimeout based on the environment.  I have a node variable (NODE_ENV) that will be set to either QA or Prod and based on the value of that variable, I want to set a corresponding value for the retryAssertionTimeout.  Here's my globals.js file ...

```
module.exports = {
    //retryAssertionTimeout: 30000,

    before: function (done) {
        console.log("test env: " + process.env.NODE_ENV)
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'qa') {
            console.log("Running in the QA environment")
            retryAssertionTimeout: 30000
        }
        done()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as below.

```
module.exports = {
    retryAssertionTimeout: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'qa' ? '4000' : '5000',
    before: function (done) {
        console.log("Environment Selected: " + process.env.NODE_ENV)
        done()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the suggested code into my globals.js file (I specified 10000 for the qa timeout value).  I then created and ran a simple test like so ...
module.exports = {
'Simple Test': function (browser) {
console.log("*** retryAssertionTimeout: " + browser.globals.retryAssertionTimeout)
browser.waitForElementVisible('.someFakeSelector')
}
}
The output is ....
C:\git\portal-ui-tests>node nightwatch tests/simpleTest.js
Environment Selected: qa

## [Simple Test] Test Suite

i Connected to localhost on port 4444 (10061ms).
Using: firefox (77.0.1) on windows 10.0 platform.

Running:  Simple Test

*** retryAssertionTimeout: 10000
× Timed out while waiting for element <.someFakeSelector> to be present for 5000 milliseconds. - expected "visible" but got: "not found" (5085ms)
So it looks like retryAssertionTimeout is being set but it's not being used when I call waitForElementVisible.